# List Comprehension: ignore element if it is a substring of another element in the same list

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have the following list

`lst = ['abc-123', 'bc', 'bcd-234', 'def-543', 'ijk-092', 'd']`

using a combination of list comprehension and filters I can end up with this result

`lst = ['abc-123', 'bcd-234', 'def-543', 'ijk-092']`

the code I use 
`lst = [x for x in lst if len(filter(lambda elem: x in elem, lst)) == 1]`

how would i do it purely as a list comphrehension, I have tried
`lst = [y for x in lst for y in lst if y in x and x != y]`

but this returns the substrings instead 
`['bc', 'bc', 'd', 'd']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every element depends on previous elements admitted, to use "pure" list comprehension, you have to take slices of the original list for every element tested during construction of the new list.

To illustrate this, this code works:

```
L=[]
for l in lst:
  a=[l in x for x in L]
  if True in a: continue
  L.append(l)
```

Converting this loop to "pure" list comprehension,

```
L=[]
L=[l for l in lst if True not in [l in x for x in L]]
```

requires that the latter `L` refer to the updated `L` within the current outer loop, which is not the case.

To make this work, the latter `L` must be replaced with a slice of the original list, `lst`, as

```
L=[l for i,l in enumerate(lst) if True not in [l in x for x in lst[0:i]]]
```

where the slice includes the elements eliminated from the final list, `L`.

The result is

```
['abc-123', 'bcd-234', 'def-543', 'ijk-092']
```

as desired.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this.... I couldn't get my head around this! Brilliant!